# Solving the system $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

When solving the following matrix equation:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 6 & 9 & 7 \\
-1 & -3 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$

I first turn $A$ into reduced row echelon form:

$R=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

And then I write the pivot variables ($x_1$ and $x_3$) in terms of the free variables ($x_2$ and $x_4$):

$x_1 = -3x_2 + x_4 \\
x_3 = -x_4$

Which then becomes the solution to the equation:

$x=
\begin{bmatrix}
-3x_2 + x_4 \\
x_2 \\
-x_4 \\
x_4
\end{bmatrix} \\
x=
x_2
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ x_4
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$

I understand that pivot variables can be written in terms of the free variables only. However, my question is why does writing the free variables in terms of the pivot variables invalid?

I understand that free variables cannot be expressed in terms of the pivot variables as other free variables get involved as well. However, why does it not work? I'm struggling to think of a reason for why it shouldn't work.

For instance, if I were to write the free variables in terms of the pivot variables:

$3x_2=-x_1+x_4\Rightarrow x_2 = -\frac{1}{3}x_1 + \frac{1}{3}x_4\\x_4=-x_3$

$x=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
-\frac{1}{3}x_1 + \frac{1}{3}x_4 \\
x_3 \\
-x_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
x_1\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-\frac{1}{3} \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+x_3
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
+x_4
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\frac{1}{3} \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

I hope this question makes sense.'

Edit: I'm really sorry. I made a typo in my initial matrix $A$. The entry in row 1 and column 4 should be a $2$ not a $3$.

Comment: Seems to me like you could do it either way in this instance but with the RREF in hand it is just simpler to use the pivot variables (e.g. because you will not have to divide by $3$ as you did the other way). In general there are lots of ways to write a solution space as a span of a set of vectors and different algorithms may yield different looking results (that nevertheless represent the same space). The point of most textbook linear algebra algorithms is just to take out as much choice as possible and do things only one way.

Comment: Forgetting what $A$ is for a minute, note that if the row 2, column 4 entry of $R$ had turned out to be a $0$ and not a $1$, $x_4$ would still be a free variable but it would not be possible to write $x_4$ in terms of $x_3$. The variable $x_3$ would just be $0$ in every element of the solution space.

Comment: $R$ is incorrect. Rank should be $3$.

Comment: Good point, it should be $3$. Because I didn't even look at what $A$ was in my comments, please just imagine them applying to the matrix equation $Rx = 0$.

Comment: @leslietownes sorry, check out my edit, I made a typo for the matrix $A$

Comment: It is *occasionally* possible to write all the variables in terms of the pivot variables, by good luck. It is *always* possible to write all the variables in terms of the free variables.

Comment: You didn't fix the first half of the post, so now the first half and the second half deal with different systems.

Comment: You could imagine that instead of trying to have pivots in the columns in order as possible, you like to have them in the first available columns in the order $2,4,3,1$ instead.... that's perfectly sensible and you can do Gaussian elimination with that in mind. You'll get an answer in which $x_2$ will definitely be a pivot variable, and with a large likelihood that either $x_3$ or $x_1$ will play the role of free variables.

Comment: Following up on Greg Martin's comment, here you can rewrite it because you have only one free variable and none of the  pivot variables must equal $0$, so you can essentially pick whichevery of the four you want to be free and solve for the others in terms of it. But if you had that one of the pivot variables must be zero, or that you had more free variables than pivots, then you might run into problems trying to do this.

Comment: Oh I see, so basically in some cases (e.g. when a pivot variable is equal to zero), it is not possible to write the free variable in terms of the pivot variables. Thank you for all of your responses!